Is comparing an INT with lower value faster?
For example these to comparisons:

If (1 < 10)..
If (1.000.000.000 < 2.000.000.000)..

Is the first comparison faster?
Is this true for all languages or interpreters?

I think this would entirely depend on whether or not you are doing the comparison with a single instruction (i.e. both integers fit into single registers and you can directly compare them) or if you need to define the integers in software (i.e. they are too large to fit into a single register and we have a custom class in our language for huge integers). For the former, I see no reason why the speed would be different unless your architecture for integer comparison has variable timing. For the latter, it would be faster to compare smaller integers because you would be doing fewer comparisons.

At least up to values that will fit in an int64_t in compiled languages the hardware compare operation has uniform execution time - it is the conditional branch that takes extra time if branch prediction guesses wrong. Huge arbitrary precision numbers the cost to compare scales with the size in memory of the integers being compared. For some prehistoric interpreted languages it might depend on the actual number of characters in the numeric value string.

No, integer operation speed is independent of value of the variable in low-level native languages (as opposed to conditional branches due to branch prediction which is dependent of the outcome of the comparison but not the actual integer values). Note some languages like Java and Python can do optimizations for short integers that are not available for big ones. For Java, this is true only for integer objects and not for native ones. For Python, this is because the language support arbitrary big numbers. Few things are true in all languages. Please focus on one specific language.

By the way, compilers can optimize out such a code and just remove the condition. This is trivial for compilers to do that when optimizations are enabled. All mainstream compilers (GNU/LLVM/MS compiler stacks) of famous native languages (C/C++/FORTRAN/Rust) do that. Java/C# can also do the same AFAIK though the condition might be optimized out at runtime. Basic interpreter like CPython (standard interpreter of Python) do not do such optimization (it mostly never optimize the code).
